# Ask question - Tags - partial placeholder text truncated

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design, asking-questions

On the [**Ask a question**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) page, in the **Tags** textbox, the placeholder width is set to `19px`, so a part of the placeholder text is truncated.

[image: placeholder text truncated to]

Comment: On Meta.SO: [Placeholder text for tags is cut off on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385795/8828658)

Comment: ON SOru: [Запись показывается не полностью в меню меток](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9418/15479).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alignment issue has been fixed recently. Now the full placeholder text is displaying with out any truncation.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Issue fixed]